# How should I get list from string in Python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

I get some values from dictionary. But when I print out them It displays bottom, I need collapse them into one list.

I tried a lot of method. Also list comprehension.

**Update:**
My dictionary data is:

```
Hours= [
   {'kota': 3, 'saat': '09:00'},
   {'kota': 3, 'saat': '09:20'},
   {'kota': 3, 'saat': '09:40'},
   {'kota': 3, 'saat': '10:00'},
   {'kota': 3, 'saat': '10:20'},
   {'kota': 3, 'saat': '10:40'},
   {'kota': 2, 'saat': '11:00'},
   {'kota': 2, 'saat': '11:20'},
   {'kota': 2, 'saat': '11:40'},

]
```

And I return values from dic:

```
for hour in hours:
a = hour.get("saat")  # From dicionary
print(a)
```

My return:

```
09:00
10:00
10:20
```

But I should display them:

```
['09:00', '10:00', '10:20']
```

Comment: Please post your `dict` as well.

Comment: Can you share your attempts?

Comment: Append them to a list; `print` is purely for visual effects (like seeing what you have); it doesn't build any kind of structure.

Answer (score 3):

A list comprehension is probably the best option:

```
mylist = [hour.get("saat") for hour in Hours]
```

or

```
mylist = [hour["saat"] for hour in Hours]
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare an empty list at beginning.. Iterate through the dictionary and append each item to the list.

Print the list outside the loop once entire iteration is completed.

Answer (score 0):

You could create an empty list say mylist for example and append to list. In your code the dictionary is Hours but you have used hours in for loop.

```
mylist = []
for hour in Hours:
    mylist.append(hour.get("saat"))  # From dicionary
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
list(map(lambda x:x.get('saat'), Hours))
```

Output:

```
['09:00',
 '09:20',
 '09:40',
 '10:00',
 '10:20',
 '10:40',
 '11:00',
 '11:20',
 '11:40']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use python's list to achieve the prints you want.

```
listTmp = []
for hour in hours:
    a = hour.get("saat")  # From dicionary
    listTmp.append(a)
print(listTmp)
```

Comment: How does a string take up less memory than a list of strings? Also, because strings are immutable, repeated concatenation can get quite expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
>>> print([hour.get("saat") for hour in Hours])
['09:00', '09:20', '09:40', '10:00', '10:20', '10:40', '11:00', '11:20', '11:40']
```

Also, remember that you can change `hour.get("saat")` for just `hour["saat"]`:

```
>>> print([hour["saat"] for hour in Hours])
['09:00', '09:20', '09:40', '10:00', '10:20', '10:40', '11:00', '11:20', '11:40']
```

Also, not sure if you might need it, but you could use [`str.join(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) if you are only looking for a one line visualization on console:

```
>>> print(", ".join([hour["saat"] for hour in Hours]))
09:00, 09:20, 09:40, 10:00, 10:20, 10:40, 11:00, 11:20, 11:40
```

Comment: This may be surprising, but generators are actually slower with `str.join`. If the argument is not a list, essentially the first thing that Python does with the argument is convert it into a list. Generators are ever so slightly slower because of the overhead involved.

Comment: @Tomothy32, ohh, I didn't know that!